# using array of array of list of lists? C#

Tags: arrays, list, dictionary

Im not an IT guy and trying some programming in his spare time and was wondering how to tackle following issue. It must be very very simple but can`t figure it out, even after dozen of read articles on stackoverflow.

I have a series of values which I need to put in a list or array which goes in another array or list. Like this:

Series one:
  
    `"name","Madman"
    "dateOfBirth", 11/03/1990 //which is a DateTime object.
    "hobby","chopping up family members"`
 
Series two

    `"name","Dad"
    "dateOfBirth", 11/03/1965 //which is a DateTime object.
    "hobby","biking"`
 
Series one and two go in another list like this:

allSeries: Series one, Series two

Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Comment: What programming language are you planning to use?

Comment: Why not make classes, put the data into the classes, and have a list of classes. OOP

Comment: the data from these arrays is going to the database right away, I dont need the classes? Seems like overkill?

Comment: If the data is going into the database why not use entity framework to generate the classes for you? Best of both worlds.

Comment: maybe Ill just use classes. looks the most simple solution. Thanks

Comment: what is an entity framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class (possibly named `Person`) that has attributes name, dateOfBirth, and hobby (this encapsulates the data).  Set the data through a constructor or setter methods.  Then store the instances of `Person` into a list, or array, or whatever you choose - probably called `people`.  Example: `List<Person> people = new List<Person>();`.

In your original approach you would have had to have declared your storage data structure as a more generic type.  A nice bonus of this approach is that you know the types of the data stored in the class.

Answer (score 1):

so depending on the language you are using you would make another list/array and make an array of arrays (or array of lists). Which language are you using? in Java you would make a `List<List<String>>` object for example and add things like this. Hope this is a start.

Edit: for c# see: http://www.dotnetperls.com/nested-list

Answer (score 1):

I would do this: create a class containing your attributes, then place multiple instances in a list.

```
public class Person
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Date dateOfBirth {get; set;}
    public string hobby {get;set;}
}
```

And place them in a list like so: `{person1; person2,...}`